# Adding objects into vectors when reading in from a file

Tags: c++

Having issues with adding a csv file seperated by , into a protein object. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
   vector<Protein> proteins;
    
      Protein prot;
    
     // load disprot database of intrinsically disordered proteins
     std::ifstream reading;
     reading.open("C:\\Users\\james\\CLionProjects\\untitled1\\disprot.csv");
     std::string line, col;
     if (reading.is_open()){
         while (reading.good()){
    
             std::getline(reading, line);
             std::stringstream ss(line);
             while(std::getline(ss, col, ',')){
                Protein temp(ss.get(), ss.get(),ss.get(),col.get_allocator())
                proteins.push_back(prot);
             }
         }
            reading.close();
        }
         else if(!reading.is_open()) throw std::runtime_error("Could not open file");
```

Comment: Could you display any errors you're getting, what exactly is failing or an example of the CSV file? It will help people on Stack Overflow to more easily give you an answer.

Comment: I don't exactly know your code but the part.   proteins.push_back(prot);.   Seems to be wrong I think you ment     ment     proteins.push_back(temp);. because you always init temp but never change prot in the for loop

Comment: @justaguyjug Sure but that temp object was me mucking around with trying to create a Protein object from reading the CSV seperated by commas and that is where I am stuck.

Comment: :@user2205930  CSV is sepetayed by commas, i get exit code -1073741819. One line of the CSV is: "Q9HFQ6","MSTEASVSYAALILADAEQEITSEKLLAITKAAGANVDQVWADVFAKAVEGKNLKELLFSFAAAAPASGAAAGSASGAAAGGEAAAEEAAEEEAAEESDDDMGFGLFD","############################################################################################################",0.